# LocationManager singleton didUpdateLocations not getting called

Tags: ios, swift, mobile

I have created a singleton LocationManager class to handle location updates in my application. In the first view controller the shared instance is accessed in `viewDidLoad` and a call to `getCurrentLocation` is made. "Getting users location..." prints to the console however the delegate method `didUpdateLocations` on the location manager is never called and the location is not updated. I have the required keys in the info.plist and the expected permissions prompts show.

I have a feeling this is a threading issue with the `LocationManager` falling out of scope but I'm not sure, would be great if someone could point me in the right direction !

Location Manager:

```
import Foundation
import CoreLocation

class LocationManager: NSObject, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

static let shared = LocationManager()
var manager: CLLocationManager!

override init() {
    super.init()
    self.manager = CLLocationManager()
    self.manager.delegate = self
    if CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() == .notDetermined {
        self.manager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    }
    self.manager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
}


public func getCurrentLocation(){
    print("Getting users location...")
    self.manager.startUpdatingLocation()
}


func locationManager(manager:CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations:[AnyObject]) {
    self.manager.stopUpdatingLocation()
    print("locations = \(locations)")
}

func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didFailWithError   error: Error) {
    print(error.localizedDescription)
}}
```

ViewController:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var titleLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var savedAreasTableView: UITableView!
    @IBOutlet weak var noSavedAreasLabel: UILabel!
    var manager: LocationManager! = LocationManager.shared

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.noSavedAreasLabel.text = "You have no saved areas available !\nTo add some, search for a location and then favourite it."

        //Check here to see if user has any favourited areas
        self.savedAreasTableView.isHidden = true
        self.noSavedAreasLabel.isHidden = false
        self.manager.getCurrentLocation()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The correct delegate function is this:

```
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, 
       didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation])
```

Comment: Was about to pinpoint this same issue... I think you nailed;)

Comment: :) sorry but I’m glad we had the same thought.

Comment: ...would only add that this protocol method is `optional` hence the compiler won’t treat it as error (but I expected at least a warning anyway).